# Is it possible to convert iframe to html?

Tags: php, html, iframe, seo

Is it possible to use PHP to convert an iFrame into on-page HTML (if that makes any sense) so that the content can be indexed by search engines? I am using a spreadsheet here:

http://www.landedhouses.co.uk/offers/

```
<p><iframe width='700' height='1200' frameborder='0' src='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Ai0rAM-RzQC4dE1hQ2FpdmFoU29POGFUR1NMQUl2RWc&#038;single=true&#038;gid=1&#038;output=html&#038;widget=true'></iframe></p>
```

Comment: In what way is an `iframe` not HTML?

Comment: `file_get_contents('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Ai0rAM-RzQC4dE1hQ2FpdmFoU29POGFUR1NMQUl2RWc&#038;single=true&#038;gid=1&#038;output=html&#038;widget=true')`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder An iFrame is not always HTML it can also be a PDF document or an MP3 or something.. But still this is quite a "stupid" question >.<

Answer: The page IS HTML, see the output=html parameter .. (LOL)

Comment: @jeremyharris This would make a proper answer to the question (rather than "just" a comment).

Comment: @Oldskool fair enough, answered. It just seemed so silly at the time I thought I might have been way off from what the OP actually wanted :)

Answer (score 2):

To pull HTML using PHP, you can use the [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function:

```
$html = file_get_contents('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Ai0rAM-RzQC4dE1‌​hQ2FpdmFoU29POGFUR1NMQUl2RWc&#038;single=true&#038;gid=1&#038;output=html&#038;wi‌​dget=true');
```

Answer (score 1):

Search engines will follow the URL inside an IFrame, unless it is forbidden by either robots.txt or meta tags.

It is difficult to include the HTML into an existing page, because at least the `<head>` and part of the `<body>` have to be removed, and probably the stylesheet fixed.

Comment: Ah that's helpful, thanks.